# Decode InvokeCommandOutput.Payload object on "@aws-sdk/client-lambda" Javascript v3 package

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

#### Describe the issue

I am invoking my lambda function like so in express.JS TypeScript,

```js
import type {InvokeCommandOutput} from '@aws-sdk/client-lambda';
import {InvokeCommand} from '@aws-sdk/client-lambda';

const command = new InvokeCommand({
  FunctionName: this.client_name,
  InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
  Payload: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(event)),
});
const response: InvokeCommandOutput = await this.client.send(command);
const payLoad = response.Payload;

if (payLoad != undefined) {
  return response.Payload;
}
```

Expecting the following response on the `InvokeCommandOutput.Payload` object from my lambda function.

```json
{
  "challenge_name": "CHALLENGE_NAME",
  "session":  "session string"
}
```

. I did this using the following package https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-lambda/index.html

I've also tried the example on  AWS as well as the `toUtf8` and `fromUtf8` functions in the SDK to decode the UINT8Array. However, they give me the following error.

```
{"errorType":"TypeError","errorMessage":"The \"key\" argument must be of type string or an instance of ArrayBuffer, Buffer, TypedArray, DataView, KeyObject, or CryptoKey. Received null","trace":["TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The \"key\" argument must be of type string or an instance of ArrayBuffer, Buffer, TypedArray, DataView, KeyObject, or CryptoKey. Received null","    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)","    at prepareSecretKey (node:internal/crypthe \"key\" argument must be of type string or ano/keys:580:11)","    at new Hmac (node:internal/crypto/hash:132:9)","    at createHmac (node:crypto:162:10)","    at AuthService.initiateAuth (/var/task/main.js:57511:48)","    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:crypto/hash:132:9)","    at createHmac (node:cry96:5)","    at async Runtime.handler (/var/task/main.js:34:9)"]}
```

#### Links

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-lambda/classes/invokecommand.html

#### Update

When when I replace....

```
if(payLoad != undefined){
                console.info(payLoad);
                return payLoad;
            }
```

...with

```
if(payLoad != undefined){
                console.info(payLoad);
                return JSON.parse(Buffer.from(payLoad).toString());
            }
```

I get the following payload.

```bash
Uint8Array(777) [
  123,  34, 101, 114, 114, 111, 114,  84, 121, 112, 101,  34,
   58,  34,  84, 121, 112, 101,  69, 114, 114, 111, 114,  34,
   44,  34, 101, 114, 114, 111, 114,  77, 101, 115, 115,  97,
  103, 101,  34,  58,  34,  84, 104, 101,  32,  92,  34, 107,
  101, 121,  92,  34,  32,  97, 114, 103, 117, 109, 101, 110,
  116,  32, 109, 117, 115, 116,  32,  98, 101,  32, 111, 102,
   32, 116, 121, 112, 101,  32, 115, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103,
   32, 111, 114,  32,  97, 110,  32, 105, 110, 115, 116,  97,
  110,  99, 101,  32,
  ... 677 more items
]
```

...that gives me the following error. Meaning there's an error in the Payload that could not be decoded.

```bash
'The "key" argument must be of type string or an instance of ArrayBuffer, Buffer, TypedArray, DataView, KeyObject, or CryptoKey. Received null'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`response.Payload` returns `Uint8Array`. You need first to convert it to a Buffer, then stringify, and then parse JSON.

Replace this line in your code:

```js
return response.Payload;
```

With this line:

```js
return JSON.parse(Buffer.from(response.Payload).toString())
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick response I am getting the following error, `The "key" argument must be of type string or an instance of ArrayBuffer, Buffer, TypedArray, DataView, KeyObject, or CryptoKey. Received null`

Comment: @JamesNganga this means your lambda returns `null`. check for error in your lambda you call. I tested my code with the working lambda and it worked, so the problem must be in the lambda you call

Comment: didn't find an error. However I am guessing the following UInt8Array being I recieved could have an issue, is that correct?

Comment: Uint8Array(777) [
  123,  34, 101, 114, 114, 111, 114,  84, 121, 112, 101,  34,
   58,  34,  84, 121, 112, 101,  69, 114, 114, 111, 114,  34,
   44,  34, 101, 114, 114, 111, 114,  77, 101, 115, 115,  97,
  103, 101,  34,  58,  34,  84, 104, 101,  32,  92,  34, 107,
  101, 121,  92,  34,  32,  97, 114, 103, 117, 109, 101, 110,
  116,  32, 109, 117, 115, 116,  32,  98, 101,  32, 111, 102,
   32, 116, 121, 112, 101,  32, 115, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103,
   32, 111, 114,  32,  97, 110,  32, 105, 110, 115, 116,  97,
  110,  99, 101,  32,
  ... 677 more items
]

Comment: @JamesNganga could it be that the error you see after decoding is coming from the Lambda you invoke?

Comment: You were right.